# Add Button to Android Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i m able to add a next button to soft keyboard but i also want to add a previous Button is this possible if yes please tell me how ?

i m trying this

[Android - add next and prev button to softkeyboard which appears on click of an edit text in my activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783875/android-add-next-and-prev-button-to-softkeyboard-which-appears-on-click-of-an)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the first answer of your own reference. It has a comment saying You cannot have both next and prev. You can have next and done but not next and prev. Just check this url. developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Comment: k i see this but can you tell me why it happens ? on click the link i got 404 Not Found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306088/need-prev-next-button-above-soft-keyboard-in-android

Comment: i also want to do same but how i can start i have no idea please help me .